# implement RESTful using the GET method

Tags: php, web-services, rest, api

I need to establish a connection and obtain a token.
The API is implemented as a RESTful web service that is accessed via HTTP using the GET method.

Parameters provided are accountid and password

Method name: api/connect

[http://api.thesite.com:12345/api/connect?account={ACCOUNTID}&pwd={PASSWORD}](http://api.thesite.com:12345/api/connect?account=%7BACCOUNTID%7D&pwd=%7BPASSWORD%7D)

In case of success, the method returns a "token id" to be passed to all subsequent API calls.

I was able to find answers for `POST`, and `PUT` but not on `GET`.

How to access the REST with PHP using GET method?

Comment: Do you want the get the token via cURL or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: as mentioned above, I need to establish a connection and obtain a token

Comment: Does my answer helped you?

Comment: No, I'm using GuzzleHttp, Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that simply with `file_get_contents`:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
   'http' => array (
      'method' => 'GET'
   )
));
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

So you can call mostly every URL via the `$url` variable. In the URL you send also your parameters like the `account` or `pwd`. I hope it was helpful.

The `$data` will be de result. When your api uses json, you can simply use `json_decode` to create an object to get the token much easier.